# receiving multiple bytes through uart avr with interrupt driven

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, uart, atmega

i'm trying to receive multiple bytes from fingerprint scanner as a response from a specific operation 
it's a 24 bytes and i used another atmega32 microcontroller to send an array

```
Identify[24] =  {0x55,0xAA,0x02,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x01};
```

the receiving microcontroller i enabled the interrupt and configured the USART correctly and i wrote the code of ISR like this

```
ISR(USART_RXC_vect){

ack[i] = UDR;
i++;

if(ack[6]==0x00)
{
    PORTA |= 0x01;
    send_uart(ack[22]);

}
if((ack[22]==0x02))
{
    PORTA |=0x02;
}
```

}

i put leds to check if it works or no and it works but the problem is i don't want to write the code inside my ISR i just want the ISR to receive the incoming data and store it in the ack array , then i use the ack array through my whole code and inside any functions

Comment: What's `i`? Is it defined? Initialized? How can you check `ack[whatever]` before it has a received value?

Comment: @EugeneSh.i is defined as a global variable and intialized by zero but i just wrote the ISR code 
and i check by connecting 2 leds one in pinA1  and the another on pinA2
for example i know the sent value of identity[1] is 0xAA on the first Micro
so the received value on the ack[1] must be 0xAA i checked that by if it is true  , power the led on